# Using `environ` to make a list of environments?

Tags: lists, theorems

In my document I use an `amsthm` environment called `question`, which I use to, well, pose questions to  myself for later reference. However, they are spread out in the text.

I know `ntheorem` has a `\listoftheorems` command or something like that which does exactly what I want. However, I have quite some bad experiences with `ntheorem`concerning the use of `ntheorem`together with other packages (it only occured when I used `mathtools` and something which I have forgotten about...) which introduced quite strange bugs, so I would want to avoid `ntheorem` altogether for the moment.

So, is this possible to do this with `environ` as it provides some useful hooks? Preferably it would be nice if the list also allows me (optionally) to include a short description and of course a page number. The environment is defined as `\newtheorem{question}{Question}`.

**Edit:** I have found `thmtools` which apparently also has a command `\listoftheorems` (and a way to redefine the heading). Would it be possible to extend this command such that I am able to add a small description?

Comment: In my opinion, your new edit should be a follow-up question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Okay. Agreed. Will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all there is the `tocloft` package, that is meant for this kind of work and takes away a little of the effort in Gonzalo's answer. Also I would propose to define a new environment, so you don't have to use an extra command, but can have an actual, optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newtheorem{xquestion}{Question}

\newcommand\listxquestionsname{List of Questions}
\newlistof{question}{xquestion}{\listxquestionsname}
\newcommand\qdescription[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{xquestion}{question}%
    {\protect\makebox[2.5cm][l]{Question~\thexquestion\hfill}#1}}

\newenvironment{question}[1][]{\begin{xquestion}\qdescription{#1}}{\end{xquestion}}

\begin{document}

\listofquestion
\bigskip

\begin{question}[Optional description for question one]
Test question One
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Test question Two
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, both answers are nice. The "problem" that I have with your package is that it might introduce new bugs when I include other packages and so on and I don't know what can go wrong in the code. But I will check out the code! Maybe it is quite short. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That might be true. But I must say that in my experience it was mostly easier and less error prone to use a package than to fiddle myself with `TeX` and `LaTeX` macros. In particular when dealing with such special purpose packages, bugs and incompatibilities have been astonishingly rare.

Comment: Thanks! I have made an implementation which (seems) to work, but maybe I am *doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 6):

The following example shows one possible solution using the LaTeX kernel command `\@starttoc` to produce the new list of questions. The `\qdescription` command is used to generate an entry in the new list of questions as well as to provide an optional description:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listquestionsname{List of Questions}
\newcommand\qdescription[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{qst}{question}%
  {\protect\makebox[2.5cm][l]{Question~\thequestion\hfill}#1}}
\newcommand\listofquestions{%
  \let\listofquestions\relax % (AM)
  \section*{\listquestionsname}\@starttoc{qst}%
}
\newcommand*\l@question{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\begin{document}

\listofquestions

\begin{question}
Test question One
\qdescription{Optional description for question one}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Test question Two
\qdescription{}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]