# How to combine the listings and algorithm2e packages to be used with List of Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, algorithm2e

I want to make a "List of Algorithms and Listings" that contains both listings made with `\begin{lstlisting}...` (`listings` package) and algorithms `\begin{algorithm}...` (`algorithm2e` package).

I also want the numbering to be continuous in the List of..., no matter how I alternate between listings and algorithms.

I have tried to use the listings package to make the List of... and to put something like `\addcontentsline{lol}{section}{\numberline {\thelstlisting}This is a test}` after `\end{algorithm}`, but that entry does not get properly numbered.

10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice if you added a MWE, so we could immediately test our ideas.

Anyway, I think, using your approach with `\addcontentsline` it is sufficient to add a `\refstepcounter{lstlisting}` in front. Also I would suggest putting those two lines in front of the `\begin{algorithm}` instead of after `\end{algorithm}` as the anchor is more convenient there.

If that is not sufficient for you, you could define your own `list of listings` with the `tocloft` package and define some wrapper environments for `lstlisting` and `algorithm`. An example where you can see this is [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63859/15616) of mine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It partially solved the numbering problem. The thing is I have an algorithm that takes up the whole page and then a listing. So the numbering would be: 1. Algorithm on page 1; 2. Listing on page 2. The problem is that, if I put the `\refstepcounter...` in from of `\begin{algorithm}` then I will get 1. Algorithm on page 2; 2. Listing on page 1. If I put the code after `\begin{algorithm}`, then I will get 2. Algorithm on page 1; 1. Listing on page 2. (in this order)... any ideas? ... besides using tocloft?

Comment: @adrian: Try to add a `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it din dot work for me, but I found a workaroud by beeing careful about where I put the algorithm that takes the whole page.